# Express.js search form not returning response from api

Tags: javascript, express, post, get, amadeus

I am trying to build a simple search form in Express using the Amadeus api. I can see the data returned to the console but upon clicking the search button on my index.js the page keeps giving me  `http://localhost:3001/results/undefined?q=CPT&submit=` and doesn't resolve.
What am I missing here please? How do I access the response in key form to build my result page? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

app.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const postRouter = require('./routes/post');
const resultsRouter = require('./routes/results');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

const app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', postRouter);
app.use('/', resultsRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

Index.js

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  div.container-fluid
    div.row.justify-content-center
        p Find Your Dream Kruger Safari Package!
          form.form-inline.my-2.my-lg-0#searchBox(
                action='/results/' +   q
                method='GET'
                )
                  input.form-control.mr-sm-2(type='text', placeholder='City Code ie. LON, JHB, CPT', aria-label='Search', id='q' name='q' required)
                  button.btn.btn-success.my-2.my-sm-0(type='submit' id='submit' name="submit") Search
```

results.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/results/:q', (req, res) => {
  const q = req.query.q;
  // const result = ;
  // q = JSON.stringify(q);
  // console.log(result);
  const searchAmadeus = require('../controllers/amadeusControl.js');
  searchAmadeus.findNew(q, (err, docs) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render('results', {
        title: 'We Found Some Great Deals',
        list: docs,
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Error  finding record :' + err);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

post.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

    router.post('/results/:q', function(req, res) {
      const q = req.body.q;
      res.send(q);
      // res.send(q);
      //console.log(q);
    });
    
    module.exports = router;
```

results.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Results  
  div.find test #{body}
  div.container
    div.row
      div.col-sm
        p left col content
      div.col-sm
        tbody
          each docs in list
            tr
              td= doc
```

amadeusControl.js

```
module.exports = {
  findNew: function(q) {
    // const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    // initialize the client and authenticate
    const Amadeus = require('amadeus');
    // console.log(process.env.AMADEUS_CLIENT_ID);
    const amadeus = new Amadeus({
      'clientId': process.env.AMADEUS_CLIENT_ID,
      'clientSecret': process.env.AMADEUS_CLIENT_SECRET,
    });

    // Get list of Hotels by city code
    amadeus.shopping.hotelOffers.get({
      cityCode: q,
    }).then(function(response) {
      // console.log(response.body); // => The raw body
      console.log(response.result); // => The fully parsed result
      // console.log(response.data); // => The data attribute taken from the result
      docs = response.result;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.response); // => The response object with (un)parsed data
      console.log(error.response.request); // => The details of the request made
      console.log(error.code); // => A unique error code to identify the type of error      // END Do something with the returned data.
    });

  }};
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you would access the `:q` parameter using the `req.params` object, not the `req.body`.

But, I think you want to use `req.query` instead.

[Express req.query docs](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.query)

If you want to use the `req.body`, you will need to change your form to a POST request instead of a GET request.

Comment: Thanks so much, I changed `req.body.q` to `req.params.q` which produces `q=JHB
submit=` in the console but isnt passing the q over to the `res.render('results', ` so the page just hangs with status 400 `data: undefined`

Comment: @ZADorkMan , this error may be because you do not explicitly return `data` from the amadeus function ( I also don't see the declaration of this variable, so you should add that too) . Also in your `results.pug` , you define the variable `docs in list` and then use `doc` in the `td` item. If you are still having problems, I suggest opening a new question about this specific issue.

Comment: Thank you @Phi12ip, I've been pulling my hair out and will try it now!